# Preciso abrir um aspx em um projeto mvc4 é possível?

Tags: c#, webforms, iis, asp.net-mvc-4, web.config

Tenho um projeto MVC4, e preciso abrir uma página aspx, que é um relatório do Report Viewer.
Isso funciona rodando localmente com o IIS do Visual Studio, mas ao subir pro servidor não funciona. O Que pode ser?

Comment: Você quer abrir um ASPX qualquer ou um relatório do ReportViewer?

Comment: Quero abrir um relatório do report viewer, em uma página..
O relatório já roda em outro sistema que é em webforms, então queremos reaproveitá-lo.